# codeigniter getting an error while uploading file?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to setup the file upload in my CodeIgniter function..

But no matter what i try to do, i get an error...

Can anyone help me how to solve my issue?

My function in controller.

```
function insert_user_details(){

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('UserName', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'required');
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('Email', 'Email', 'required|email');
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('FirstName','FirstName', 'required');
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('MiddleName','FirstName', 'required');
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('LastName','FirstName', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                echo 'Please Fill in the Forms Correctly' ;
            }
            else
            {
                $config['upload_path'] = '../user_uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '100';
                $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                $config['max_height']  = '768';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $pass = $this->input->post('Password');
                $pass = md5($pass);
                $data = array(
                    'UserName'=>$this->input->post('UserName'),
                    'Password'=>$pass,
                    'FirstName'=>$this->input->post('FirstName'),
                    'MiddleNames'=>$this->input->post('MiddleName'),
                    'LastName'=>$this->input->post('LastName'),
                    'DateOfBirth'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['DateOfBirth'])),
                    'AddressLine1'=>$this->input->post('AddressLine1'),
                    'AddressLine2'=>$this->input->post('AddressLine2'),
                    'City'=>$this->input->post('City'),
                    'CountryID'=>$this->input->post('CountryID'),
                    'NationalityCountryID'=>$this->input->post('NationalityCountryID'),
                    'MobileNo'=>$this->input->post('MobileNo'),
                    'WorkPhoneNo'=>$this->input->post('WorkPhoneNo'),
                    'WorkPhoneExtention'=>$this->input->post('WorkPhoneExtension'),
                    'NationalTaxNumber'=>$this->input->post('NationalTaxNumber'),
                    'NationalIDCardNo'=>$this->input->post('NationalIDCardNo'),
                    'MaritalStausID'=>$this->input->post('UI_LanguageID'),
                    'ReligionID'=>$this->input->post('ReligionID'),
                    'Photograph' => $this->upload->data(),
                    'Email'=>$this->input->post('Email'),
                    'WebUrl'=>$this->input->post('WebUrl'),
                    'HighestEducation'=>$this->input->post('HighestEducation'),
                    'UserResumeFile'=> 'res.jpg',
                    'UI_LanguageID'=> $this->input->post('UI_LanguageID'),
                    'LastLoginDate'=>'2013-02-24 00:00:00',
                    'LastLoginIP'=>'192.168.1.2',
                    'Remarks'=>$this->input->post('Remarks'),
                    'CreateByUserID'=>'1',
                    'CreateAt'=>'2013-02-24 00:00:00',
                    'ModifiedByUserID'=>'2',
                    'ModifiedAt'=>'2013-02-24 00:00:00',
                    'IsActive'=>'1'
                );
                $table = 'sys_user_accounts';
                $this->common_model->insert_record($table, $data);
                echo 'Success Message' ;
                //$this->load->view('user_management/success','','true');
        }
    }
```

Here is the view file.

'Photograph',
        'id'          => 'Photograph',
        'placeholder' => 'Upload User Photo',
        'maxlength'   => '250'
    );
    echo form_upload($input_field_attributes);
    ?>

and yes i used the multipart

```
echo form_open_multipart('user_management/manage_users',array('id' => 'insert_user'));
```

so can anyone tell me why i am getting this below error in firebug? and how to solve it??

```
> Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `sys_user_accounts` (`UserName`, `Password`, `FirstName`, `MiddleNames`, `LastName`, `DateOfBirth`, `AddressLine1`, `AddressLine2`, `City`, `CountryID`, `NationalityCountryID`, `MobileNo`, `WorkPhoneNo`, `WorkPhoneExtention`, `NationalTaxNumber`, `NationalIDCardNo`, `MaritalStausID`, `ReligionID`, `Photograph`, `Email`, `WebUrl`, `HighestEducation`, `UserResumeFile`, `UI_LanguageID`, `LastLoginDate`, `LastLoginIP`, `Remarks`, `CreateByUserID`, `CreateAt`, `ModifiedByUserID`, `ModifiedAt`, `IsActive`) VALUES ('hello', '1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72', 'fda', 'fda', 'fad', '2010-03-03', '1', 0, '1', 0, 0, '1', '1', 0, '1', 0, 0, 0, Array, 0, 0, 0, 'res.jpg', 0, '2013-02-24 00:00:00', '192.168.1.2', 0, '1', '2013-02-24 00:00:00', '2', '2013-02-24 00:00:00', '1')

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\zorkif_nextgen\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with CI, but I can see that `$this->upload->data();` is returning an Array and that's why it's throwing an error.

If you are using PHP 5.4 try using `$this->upload->data()['file_name']` or `$this->upload->data()['full_path']` and if you are using PHP 5.3 or lower, than simply assign `$this->upload->data()` to some variable and than access values via proper keys.

Just before inserting do this `var_dump($this->upload->data());` and I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: Got your Point Thanks. But i am getting nothing, empty on $this->upload->data()['file_name']
why it is not getting any value??

Comment: Try `var_dump($this->upload->data());` and see what values it contains.

Answer (score 0):

On your $data array, 'Photograph' index you are assigning $this->upload->data(). Actually $this->upload->data() this helper function return an array. Details [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

If you are trying to save the name of the photograph, try this

```
$name = $this->upload->data();
```

Then in your array

```
'Photograph' => $name['file_name']
```

Comment: im not getting your point??
how should i write then, 
the link you provided, i already have seen that documentation.
can you tell me in which line what should i update?

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the `$this->upload->do_upload('image_file_name')` // Your actual input filed name

and before uploading do check the condition
    //Check whether uploaded successfully or not

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_file_name'))
{
    // If all uploading condition not mate like image size/type etc.
}
```

Comment: I cant see the image file validation. if image upload criteria wont satisfied than how you will handle this. Better validate the uploaded image files against 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

Comment: check the image upload controller functionality [Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 0):

`'Photograph' => $this->upload->data()`

$this->upload->data() is a CI function that returns an array, so to insert it into a column in the DB you will either need to serialize it, changes it to a string or just set one value from the array for the Photograph field.